# Horizontal submenu (dropdown) in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, submenu, horizontallist

I am trying to get the submenu in Bootstrap's navbar to open horizontally, instead of vertically.

I hoped this would be something as simple as adding an extra style, e.g.

```
ul.dropdown-menu li {
    display:inline;
}
```

or

```
.navbar-nav li.dropdown li {
  display:inline;
}
```

but nothing changes.

I couldn't find anything useful after quite a bit of searching either. Hope to get some help here.

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking for exactly. Do you want the original menu but the opening animation to go from left-to-right? Or were you looking for more like a mega-menu where you can have multiple columns?

Comment: When you click on a drop down, the submenu unfolds vertically. I want to make it unfold horizontally. No, I do not want a multiple-column menu. I want the second menu row to position itself underneath the main, and the items in it to be stacked horizontally. This is what `display:inline` normally does.

Comment: Superfish does this and then there's SuperClick that works with it. It's a pain in the ass in Bootstrap, I still haven't implemented it anywhere: https://jsbin.com/riharu/1/

Comment: Could you please post this as an answer so that I could select it? And if you care to explain the logic, that would be great: I have been playing with this for an hour now, and while my own menu appears to be exactly the same (classes-wise), I can't get it to work like this. The only thing that works is directly copy your menu and replace the links inside - which does work but I'd still prefer to use my menu, which is dynamically generated (php).

Comment: This is set up exactly like a Bootstrap menu should be, the only thing different is the CSS at the min-width. Take a look at the GetBootstrap.com documentation on the menu.